# How to read CDATA using XmlReader in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I am able to read xml using XmlReader, but not able to read xml's CDATA portion.

How to read it ?

Below is my code

```
private void ParseDataValueNode(XmlReader CmdNode, Message Msg)
        {
            int DataValueNodeCount = 0;
            while (CmdNode.Read())
            {
                if (CmdNode.Name.Equals("DataValue") && CmdNode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    DataValueNodeCount++;
                    ParseDataValueNode(CmdNode, Msg, DataValueNodeCount, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

XML

```
  <Response Id="2">
    <Information>
      <![CDATA[ <DataValue Name="abc" Value="dddd"/> <DataValue Name="ccc" Value="ffff"/> <DataValue Name="ddd" Value="dfdf"/> ]]>
    </Information>
  </Response>
```

If xml doesn't contain `CDATA` then it works perfectly fine, however in case `CDATA` it doesn't read elements under CDATA

Comment: Everything inside CDATA is a single text() node. You need to start a new reader for that DocumentFragment

Answer (score 2):

The data inside the `CDATA` section is treated as plain text. You need to load it's contents into the new `DOMDocument`.
You can recognize the CDATA using this code:

```
if (CmdNode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
```